# Simple photomosaic generator

Tags: performance, beginner, c, programming-challenge, c99

I wrote an implementation of Robert Heaton's [Programming Exercise for Advanced Beginners #4 (photomosaics)](https://robertheaton.com/2018/11/03/programming-project-4-photomosaics/) in C99 using the [MagickCore](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php) library. The full code is as follows:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <MagickCore/MagickCore.h>

#define DIE(rc, fmt, ...)               { fprintf(stderr, "FATAL: "fmt"\n", __VA_ARGS__); exit(rc); }
#define WARN(fmt, ...)                  { fprintf(stderr, "WARN: " fmt"\n", __VA_ARGS__); }
#define assert_error(expression, s)     if(!expression) { perror(s); abort(); }

typedef struct {
    unsigned int r, g, b;
} Pixel;
typedef enum { L, UL, XU, XUL, F } NUM_TYPES;

#define MAX_FN_LEN 150
#define IMG_LIST_MAX_SIZE 5091

static const char *cache_filename = "/home/wilson/.cache/photomosaics/avgs";
static char *cache_buf = NULL;
static size_t cache_max_size;
static ssize_t initial_cache_size = 1;
static ssize_t cache_size = 0;
static time_t cache_mtime;
static long *deletables;
static size_t deletables_ind = 0;
static char temp_dirname[] = "/tmp/photomosaics-XXXXXX";
static char **inner_cache_tmp_files;
static char **files_inner_cached = NULL;
static size_t files_inner_cached_ind = 0;

static void try(int exit_code, char *function_name) {
    if(exit_code != 0) perror(function_name);
}
static size_t slen(const char *s, size_t maxlen) {
    char *pos = memchr(s, '\0', maxlen);
    return pos ? (size_t)(pos - s) : maxlen;
}
static size_t indof(const char *s, char ch, size_t maxlen) {
    char *pos = memchr(s, ch, maxlen);
    return pos ? (size_t)(pos - s) : maxlen;
}

static bool parse_num(const char *str, NUM_TYPES type, void *out) {
    char *endptr;
    const char *old_locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    setlocale(LC_ALL|~LC_NUMERIC, "");
    errno = 0;
    int my_errno = 0;

    switch(type) {
    case L:
        *((long *)out) = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
        break;
    case UL:
        *((unsigned long *)out) = strtoul(str, &endptr, 10);
        break;
    case XU: {
            unsigned long tmp = strtoul(str, &endptr, 16);
            if(tmp > UINT_MAX) my_errno = ERANGE;
            else *((unsigned int *)out) = tmp;
        }
        break;
    case XUL:
        *((unsigned long *)out) = strtoul(str, &endptr, 16);
        break;
    case F:
        *((float *)out) = strtof(str, &endptr);
        break;
    }

    setlocale(LC_ALL, old_locale);
    if(errno) return false;
    if(my_errno) { 
        errno = my_errno;
        return false;
    }
    /*N.B. fails on "partial" conversions or if str is empty*/
    return *str != '\0' && *endptr == '\0';
}
/*static bool parse_float(char *str, float *out) {*/
/*    return parse_num(str, F, out);*/
/*}*/
/*static bool parse_long(char *str, long *out) {*/
/*    return parse_num(str, L, out);*/
/*}*/
static bool parse_hex_tou(char *str, unsigned int *out) {
    return parse_num(str, XU, out);
}
static bool parse_ulong(char *str, unsigned long *out) {
    return parse_num(str, UL, out);
}

static Pixel hexstr_top(const char *hs) {
    char rstr[3] = {hs[0], hs[1],};
    char gstr[3] = {hs[2], hs[3],};
    char bstr[3] = {hs[4], hs[5],};
    Pixel p;
    parse_hex_tou(rstr, &p.r);
    parse_hex_tou(gstr, &p.g);
    parse_hex_tou(bstr, &p.b);
    return p;
}

static ssize_t cache_grep(char *key) {
    if(cache_size == -1)
        return -1;
    if(!cache_buf) {
        /* init cache */
        errno = 0;
        FILE *cache_file = fopen(cache_filename, "r");
        struct stat cache_st;
        if(!cache_file) {
            WARN("Couldn't open cache file '%s'. "
                "Please ensure the directory exists.", cache_filename);
            perror("fopen");
        }
        else {
            if(stat(cache_filename, &cache_st) == 0)
                errno = 0;
            else if(errno == ENOENT) {
                /* create the file and try again just in case that's the only error */
                errno = 0;
                FILE *tmp_cache_file = fopen(cache_filename, "a");
                if(!tmp_cache_file) {
                    WARN("Couldn't open cache file '%s'. "
                        "Please ensure the directory exists.", cache_filename);
                    perror("fopen");
                }
                else {
                    try(fclose(tmp_cache_file), "fclose");
                    if(stat(cache_filename, &cache_st) != 0) {
                        WARN("Could not stat cache file '%s'", cache_filename);
                        perror("stat");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(errno) {
            WARN("Will stop attempting to cache to '%s' for the remainder of execution.", cache_filename);
            cache_size = -1;
            return -1;
        }

        /* No errors, proceed to populate cache_buf */

        cache_mtime = cache_st.st_mtime;
        long cache_file_size = cache_st.st_size;
        /* The following 2 mallocs are guesses; will realloc later if needed */
        cache_max_size = (cache_file_size < 5822 ? 5822 : cache_file_size) + 5 * MAX_FN_LEN;
        cache_buf = malloc(cache_max_size);
        deletables = malloc(50 * sizeof(long));
        initial_cache_size = cache_size = fread(cache_buf, 1, cache_file_size, cache_file);
        cache_buf[cache_size] = 0; /* For the initial strncat later */

        assert(cache_size == cache_file_size);
        try(fclose(cache_file), "fclose");
    }

    if(cache_size == 0) return -1;

    char filename[MAX_FN_LEN];
    struct stat file_st;

    for(ssize_t i=0; i < cache_size; i += indof(cache_buf + i, '\n', cache_size - i) + 1) {
        /* If we already marked it for deletion, we want the image's cache entry which
           we put at the bottom of the buffer, in case the avg color has changed. */
        bool skip = false;
        for(size_t j=0; j < deletables_ind; j++) {
            if(deletables[j] == i) {
                skip = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(skip) continue;
        size_t fn_len = 0;
        size_t fn_begin = i;
        for(; i < cache_size; i++) {
            if((filename[i-fn_begin]=cache_buf[i]) == '\t') {
                fn_len = i - fn_begin;
                filename[fn_len] = '\0';
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
        assert(fn_len);
        if(!strncmp(filename, key, fn_len)) {
            //Already exists in cache
            try(stat(filename, &file_st), "stat");
            //The sole use of `initial_...`. Prevents the caller from re- and recaching newly-added files
            if(i > initial_cache_size - 1 || file_st.st_mtime < cache_mtime) {
                /* Cache entry is up to date */
                return i;
            }
            /* Not up to date. Caller will create a new cache entry,
               then we will delete this line at the end of the program */
            if(deletables_ind > 49) {
                deletables = realloc(deletables, (deletables_ind + 1) * sizeof(deletables[0]));
                assert_error(deletables, "realloc");
            }
            deletables[deletables_ind++] = fn_begin;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
static bool cache_fetch(char *key, Pixel *value) {
    ssize_t i = cache_grep(key);
    if(i == -1) return false;
    char hexstr[7];
    assert(indof(cache_buf + i, '\n', cache_size - i) == 6);
    hexstr[0] = 0;
    strncat(hexstr, cache_buf + i, 6);
    *value = hexstr_top(hexstr);
    return true;
}
static bool cache_put(char *key, Pixel value) {
    if(!cache_buf) return false;
    char entry[MAX_FN_LEN + 9];
    int entry_length = sprintf(entry, "%s\t%02x%02x%02x\n", key, value.r, value.g, value.b);
    size_t new_size_of_cache = cache_size + entry_length + 1;
    if(new_size_of_cache > cache_max_size) {
        cache_buf = realloc(cache_buf, new_size_of_cache);
        assert_error(cache_buf, "realloc");
        cache_max_size = new_size_of_cache;
    }
    strncat(cache_buf, entry, entry_length);
    cache_size = new_size_of_cache - 1;
    return true;
}


static Pixel get_avg_color(unsigned char *pixels, const size_t pixels_column_cnt, const ssize_t x, const ssize_t y, const size_t width, const size_t height) {
    Pixel p = {0};
    int i = y * pixels_column_cnt + x * 3;
    for(unsigned long c=0; c < width*height;) {
        p.r += pixels[i++];
        p.g += pixels[i++];
        p.b += pixels[i++];
        if(++c % width == 0)
            i += (pixels_column_cnt - width) * 3; //next row ...
    }

    p.r /= width*height;
    p.g /= width*height;
    p.b /= width*height;
    return p;
}

static bool get_resized_pixel_info(char *filename, const size_t width, const size_t height, unsigned char *pixels_out, ExceptionInfo *exception) {
    if(!files_inner_cached) {
        inner_cache_tmp_files = malloc(IMG_LIST_MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
        files_inner_cached = malloc(IMG_LIST_MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
    }
    const size_t pixels_arr_size = width * height * 3;
    bool file_is_cached = false;
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i < files_inner_cached_ind; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(files_inner_cached[i], filename)) {
            file_is_cached = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(file_is_cached) {
        FILE *inner_cache = fopen(inner_cache_tmp_files[i], "rb");
        assert_error(inner_cache, "fopen");
        size_t z = fread(pixels_out, 1, pixels_arr_size, inner_cache);
        fclose(inner_cache);
        return z == pixels_arr_size;
    }
    else {
        if(files_inner_cached_ind == 0)
            mkdtemp(temp_dirname);
        const size_t filename_len = strlen(filename);
        const size_t dirname_len = strlen(temp_dirname);
        char *temp_name = malloc(filename_len);
        char *temp_path = malloc(filename_len + dirname_len + 2);
        temp_name[0] = 0;
        strncat(temp_name, filename, filename_len);
        /* TODO gracefully handle slashes (?) and percents in the filenames themselves */
        for(size_t c=0; c < filename_len; ++c) if(temp_name[c] == '/') temp_name[c] = '%';
        temp_path[0] = 0;
        strncat(temp_path, temp_dirname, dirname_len);
        temp_path[dirname_len] = '/';
        temp_path[dirname_len+1] = 0;
        strncat(temp_path, temp_name, filename_len);
        free(temp_name);

        FILE *inner_cache = fopen(temp_path, "wb");
        assert_error(inner_cache, "fopen");
        ImageInfo *image_info = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo *)NULL);
        image_info->filename[0] = 0;
        strncat(image_info->filename, filename, filename_len);
        Image *src_img = ReadImage(image_info, exception);
        Image *src_img_r = ResizeImage(src_img, width, height, LanczosFilter, exception);

        if(!src_img_r) MagickError(exception->severity, exception->reason, exception->description);
        ExportImagePixels(src_img_r, 0, 0, width, height, "RGB", CharPixel, pixels_out, exception);
        if(exception->severity != UndefinedException) CatchException(exception);
        DestroyImage(src_img);
        DestroyImage(src_img_r);
        DestroyImageInfo(image_info);
        assert(fwrite(pixels_out, 3, pixels_arr_size / 3, inner_cache) == pixels_arr_size / 3);
        fclose(inner_cache);
        inner_cache_tmp_files[files_inner_cached_ind] = malloc(strlen(temp_path) + 1);
        strcpy(inner_cache_tmp_files[files_inner_cached_ind], temp_path);
        files_inner_cached[files_inner_cached_ind] = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
        files_inner_cached[files_inner_cached_ind][0] = 0;
        strncat(files_inner_cached[files_inner_cached_ind++], filename, filename_len);
        free(temp_path);
        return true;
    }
}

static unsigned char *get_img_with_closest_avg(char *img_list, size_t img_list_size, Pixel p, const size_t width, const size_t height, ExceptionInfo *exception) {
    const size_t pixels_arr_size = width * height * 3;
    unsigned char *pixels_of_closest = malloc(pixels_arr_size);
    unsigned char *pixels = malloc(pixels_arr_size);
    float distance_of_closest = sqrtf(powf(0xff, 2) * 3); //max diff value
    bool test_pxofcls_populated = false;

    for(size_t c=0; c < img_list_size;) {
        Pixel avg;
        bool fetched_avg_from_cache = cache_fetch(&img_list[c], &avg);
        if(!fetched_avg_from_cache) {
            assert(get_resized_pixel_info(&img_list[c], width, height, pixels, exception));
            avg = get_avg_color(pixels, width, 0, 0, width, height);
            assert(cache_put(&img_list[c], avg));
        }
        long rdiff = (long)avg.r - p.r;
        long gdiff = (long)avg.g - p.g;
        long bdiff = (long)avg.b - p.b;
        float new_distance = sqrtf(powf(rdiff, 2) + powf(gdiff, 2) + powf(bdiff, 2));
        if(new_distance < distance_of_closest) {
            distance_of_closest = new_distance;
            if(fetched_avg_from_cache)
                assert(get_resized_pixel_info(&img_list[c], width, height, pixels, exception));
            // For now, return any perfect match
            if(new_distance < 0.01f) {
               free(pixels_of_closest);
               return pixels;
            }
            memcpy(pixels_of_closest, pixels, pixels_arr_size);
            test_pxofcls_populated = true;
        }
        c += slen(&img_list[c], img_list_size - c) + 1;
    }
    assert(test_pxofcls_populated);
    free(pixels);
    return pixels_of_closest;
}

static Image *photomosaic(Image *image, const size_t each_width, const size_t each_height, ExceptionInfo *exception) {
    const size_t pixel_cnt = image->columns * image->rows;
    unsigned char *pixels = malloc(pixel_cnt * 3);
    FILE *f = popen("find $(find ~/pics -type d | grep -vE 'redacted|not_real') -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0", "r");
    char buf[IMG_LIST_MAX_SIZE];
    size_t bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, IMG_LIST_MAX_SIZE, f);
    try(pclose(f), "pclose");

    assert(ExportImagePixels(image, 0, 0, image->columns, image->rows, "RGB", CharPixel, pixels, exception));

    for(size_t i=0, j=0; i < pixel_cnt;) {
        /*Specifying 0 for y allows us to automatically use i to "roll over" into next row*/
        Pixel p = get_avg_color(pixels, image->columns, i, 0, each_width, each_height);
        unsigned char *new_pixels = get_img_with_closest_avg(buf, bytes_read, p, each_width, each_height, exception);
        for(size_t c=0; c < each_width*each_height;) {
            pixels[j] = new_pixels[c*3];
            pixels[j+1] = new_pixels[c*3+1];
            pixels[j+2] = new_pixels[c*3+2];
            j += 3;
            if(++c % each_width == 0)
                j += (image->columns - each_width) * 3; //next row ...
        }
        i += each_width; //next splotch
        /*If this row is done, skip over all the rows we just splotched*/
        if(i % image->columns == 0)
            i += image->columns * (each_height - 1);
        j = i * 3;
        free(new_pixels);
    }
    Image *new_image = ConstituteImage(image->columns, image->rows, "RGB", CharPixel, pixels, exception);
    free(pixels);
    if(!new_image)
        MagickError(exception->severity, exception->reason, exception->description);
    return new_image;
}

void usage(char *progname) {
    fprintf(stderr,
        "Usage: %s (-h | (-i <input_file> -o <output_file> -w <width> -l <length>))\n"
        "\t-h\tPrint this help message and exit.\n"
        "\tThis program creates a photomosaic by replacing each block\n\t"
        "of 'input_file' of size 'width' x 'length' by the resized\n\t"
        "version of some image with a similar average color.\n\t"
        "Writes the new image to the filename specified by 'output_file'.\n"
        "\n\nExit status:\n"
        "\t0\tSpecified operation succeeded\n"
        "\t1\tError reading or performing some operation on an image\n"
        "\t2\tError parsing command line arguments\n"
        , progname);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ExceptionInfo *exception;
    Image *input_img, *output_img = NULL;
    const size_t max_fn_len = 400;
    char input_img_filename[max_fn_len];
    input_img_filename[0] = 0;
    char output_img_filename[max_fn_len];
    output_img_filename[0] = 0;
    ImageInfo *image_info, *new_image_info = NULL;
    size_t length = 1, width = 1;

    int opt;
    while((opt=getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:l:w:")) > -1) {
        switch(opt) {
        case 'h':
            usage(argv[0]);
            return 0;
        case 'i':
            if(slen(optarg, max_fn_len) == max_fn_len) DIE(2, "Argument \"%s\" to option -i should be less than %zu characters.", optarg, max_fn_len)
            strncat(input_img_filename, optarg, max_fn_len - 1);
            break;
        case 'l':
            if(!parse_ulong(optarg, &length))
                DIE(2, "Argument \"%s\" to option -l could not be parsed to an unsigned long int.", optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            if(slen(optarg, max_fn_len) == max_fn_len) DIE(2, "Argument \"%s\" to option -o should be less than %zu characters.", optarg, max_fn_len)
            strncat(output_img_filename, optarg, max_fn_len - 1);
            break;
        case 'w':
            if(!parse_ulong(optarg, &width))
                DIE(2, "Argument \"%s\" to option -w could not be parsed to an unsigned long int.", optarg);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(slen(input_img_filename, max_fn_len) < 1)  DIE(2, "No input image specified.%s", "");
    if(slen(output_img_filename, max_fn_len) < 1) DIE(2, "No output image specified.%s", "");

    MagickCoreGenesis(*argv, MagickTrue);
    exception = AcquireExceptionInfo();

    image_info = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo *)NULL);
    strcpy(image_info->filename, input_img_filename);
    input_img = ReadImage(image_info, exception);
    if(exception->severity != UndefinedException)
        CatchException(exception);
    if(!input_img)
        DIE(1, "Input image %s could not be read.", input_img_filename);

    output_img = photomosaic(input_img, width, length, exception);

    if(exception->severity != UndefinedException)
        CatchException(exception);


    /* Teardown */
    if(files_inner_cached) {
        for(size_t i=0; i < files_inner_cached_ind; i++) {
            try(remove(inner_cache_tmp_files[i]), "remove");
            free(inner_cache_tmp_files[i]);
            free(files_inner_cached[i]);
        }
        try(remove(temp_dirname), "remove");
    }
    if(cache_buf) {
        FILE *cache = fopen(cache_filename, "w");
        if(!cache) {
            WARN("Failed to reopen the cache file '%s' for writing "
                "in order to update the cache properly:", cache_filename);
            perror("fopen");
            WARN("The cache at '%s' may now contain duplicate entries.", cache_filename);
        }
        else for(ssize_t i=0; i < cache_size;) {
            bool keep = true;
            for(size_t j=0; j < deletables_ind; j++) {
                if(deletables[j] == i) {
                    keep = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            size_t line_len = indof(cache_buf + i, '\n', cache_size - i);
            if(keep) for(size_t j=0; j <= line_len; j++) assert(fputc(cache_buf[i+j], cache) != EOF);
            i += line_len + 1;
        }
        if(cache) fclose(cache);
        free(deletables);
        free(cache_buf);
    }

    if(output_img) {
        new_image_info = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo *)NULL);
        strcpy(output_img->filename, output_img_filename);
        WriteImage(new_image_info, output_img, exception);
        DestroyImage(output_img);
        DestroyImageInfo(new_image_info);
    }
    DestroyImage(input_img);
    DestroyImageInfo(image_info);
    DestroyExceptionInfo(exception);
    MagickCoreTerminus();
    return 0;
}
```

(can also view at https://github.com/thenewmantis/photomosaics/blob/ffb7821da62a5f6852d79889b1a3cd1f527babdf/photomosaics.c)
I compile with the following command:

```
gcc -ansi -std=c99 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -lm `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand`
```

I receive no warnings on my machine.

I am a beginner in C and looking for feedback particularly on the following things:

- Performance/speed. When creating a mosaic of a 3264x2448 input image in 24x17 blocks, it takes almost a minute and a half, which I consider reasonably good. With a 4214x2863 image broken into 7x7 blocks, it's closer to 7 minutes (is this reasonable? Opinions?). I'm wondering if there is an obviously faster way to work with the "inner cache" (the cache for each execution which stores all the pixel information for each image). My general goal with this is to have something that will run as fast as possible without the need for a large quantity of pre-existing cached data.
- "Obvious" standard ways of doing things in C99 that I may have missed. My experience learning C so far has been working through Robert Heaton's exercises one by one and using Linux manpages and StackOverflow when I need help, so there may be things that are in some book/class that every beginner has read/taken, which I am simply not aware of.
- Portability. Feel free to ignore for now that my method of creating a temp cache in `get_resized_pixel_info` will not work on Windows (the UNIX `find` command on line 367 likewise is just a placeholder which I intend to replace with some better method of supplying source images), but in general I am looking for ways to reduce my dependency on compiler specific extensions, the POSIX standard and implementation-defined outcomes. (This is why I rolled my own `slen` instead of just using `strnlen`, although I still need `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` until I define my own `mkdtemp` analogue et al.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a lot of warnings when compiling, particularly for signed/unsigned conversions and for passing string literals as `char*` (e.g. to `try()`).  These are easily fixed.

---

There's no need for `parse_num()` and the `NUM_TYPES` type.  The only call sites are within `parse_hex_tou()` and `parse_ulong()`.  And those functions' call sites are:

> ```
>     Pixel p;
>     parse_hex_tou(rstr, &p.r);
>     parse_hex_tou(gstr, &p.g);
>     parse_hex_tou(bstr, &p.b);
>     return p;
> ```

and

> ```
>     while((opt=getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:l:w:")) > -1) {
>         switch(opt) {
>         case 'l':
>             if(!parse_ulong(optarg, &length))
>                 DIE(2, "Argument \"%s\" to option -l could not be parsed to an unsigned long int.", optarg);
>             break;
>         case 'w':
>             if(!parse_ulong(optarg, &width))
>                 DIE(2, "Argument \"%s\" to option -w could not be parsed to an unsigned long int.", optarg);
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> ```

In both these cases, we'd like to set and restore the locale just once rather than for each number.  And we have undefined behaviour in a couple of places: passing a null pointer as the locale argument, and using the returned string pointer after another intervening `setlocale()` call.  We can fix both of those with a simple `old_locale = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")`.

For the first of those functions, where we completely ignore parse failures, I'd use a simple `sscanf("%2x%2x%2x")` for the conversion (and consider checking the result, or at least returning a predictable value on failure).  For the second, we can have a much simpler function which no longer requires a `switch`.

There's a portability bug that we pass address of a `size_t` to `parse_ulong`.  We need to be reading as the correct type on platforms where these are not the same type.  The best way to do that is using `sscanf("%zu")` (or perhaps `sscanf("%zu%n")` so we can check the conversion consumed the entire string).

---

We don't need to copy strings from the command-line, nor impose arbitrary limits on their length:

> ```
>     const size_t max_fn_len = 400;
>     char input_img_filename[max_fn_len];
>     input_img_filename[0] = 0;
>     char output_img_filename[max_fn_len];
>     output_img_filename[0] = 0;
> ```

We can simply have

```
    char const *input_img_filename = NULL;
    char const *output_img_filename = NULL;
```

and just assign the pointer when parsing arguments:

```
    int opt;
    while((opt=getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:l:w:")) > -1) {
        switch(opt) {
        case 'i':
            input_img_filename = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            output_img_filename = optarg;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!input_img_filename)  DIE(2, "No input image specified.%s", "");
    if (!output_img_filename) DIE(2, "No output image specified.%s", "");
```

---

Usability: when we ask for help using `-h` option, the help is printed to the standard *error* stream.  I would expect that to go to the standard output stream, since the help message is then the expected output.

We should produce some error-stream output if an unrecognised option is passed, though - add a `case '?'` to handle that.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that is indeed a great set of obvious ways of doing things that I was unaware of. May I ask what compiler you are using and what warning flags? I use `-ansi -std=c99 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra` and don't get any warnings.

Comment: `gcc-12 -std=c17 -fPIC -gdwarf-4 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion  -Wstrict-prototypes -fanalyzer   -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6 -isystem /usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16    282618.c   -lMagickCore-6.Q16  -o 282618`  (some of that comes from expanding `pkgconfig` output; not all written by hand!)

Comment: It's the `-Wwrite-strings` and `-Wconversion` that expose the issues that concerned me here - highly recommended.

Comment: And yes, I should have used `std=c99` for this, but forgot to change my defaults...

Comment: One more thing, you mentioned using the `"%n"` conversion specifier at the end of my `sscanf` format, but as far as I can tell, all that does is tell me how many characters the conversion consumed. So is the quickest way to convert a string and make sure there were no invalid characters just `int i; sscanf(optarg, "%zu%n", &width, &i);` then verify that `sscanf` returned 1 and that `(size_t)i == strlen(optarg)`, or is there some easier way I'm missing?

Comment: I also noticed that `"%n"` reads into a signed int for some reason. I can't find any explicit guarantee in the manpage that it would never return a negative value, but can't imagine why it would.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by using `%n` conversion.  You should be able to target a `size_t` variable by using the relevant modifier (`%zn`), if I've understood the specification correctly.  However, GCC complains _`format ‘%zn’ expects argument of type ‘signed size_t *’`_; I think that might be erroneous.

Comment: The standard requires that we use a __signed__ integer type for `%n` conversion (regardless of any length modifiers).  I've [asked on Stack Overflow about using `%zn` conversion](//stackoverflow.com/q/75193096/4850040).

Comment: The answers to that question so far lead me to believe that my initial solution of just putting it in an `int` is the move. The only thing I'll do with `i` is compare it to `strlen` which returns a `size_t`, so that seems to me like the sensible way to go about this.

Comment: I accepted the answer that suggests using `%jn` to write into a `intmax_t` variable - if you want to be really robust, you could use that.  Of course, it's impossible to exceed the range of `int` by successfully parsing an integer (and on most OSes, impossible to pass that much in a command-line argument), so perhaps this is just counting the angels that can dance on a pin-head now!

Answer (score 4):

```
static const char *cache_filename = "/home/wilson/.cache/photomosaics/avgs";
```

Recommend you define a helper function which
returns the `photomosaics/` directory,
creating it if necessary.
You might ask the OS, or consult an
env var like `$HOME`.

Similar remarks for `temp_dirname`.
Note that POSIX, and OS-specific interfaces, offer helpers
which will generate such directory names.
A usual concern is whether other programs
("attackers") can access / race with
such directories, so avoiding simple hardcodes
is a sensible habit. It's just good code hygiene.

---

Consider initializing this to arbitrary value of `0`:

```
static size_t cache_max_size;
```

In C++ we could do RAII, but as it stands I guess we need this global.

I am similarly sad that other variables like `cache_mtime`
are only sometimes valid.
There's a lot of coupling going on among these various routines.

---

```
static void try(int exit_code, char *function_name) {
    if(exit_code != 0) perror(function_name);
}
```

Yikes! I am definitely not happy with the public API
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
on that one.

Some of the usage is for functions like `fclose()`
that "cannot fail" (mostly  -- unless the disk fills).
In which case making `try` responsible for exiting
with fatal error status seems reasonable.

Other usages are for functions that seldom fail
but absolutely could, especially when the code
has just been deployed in a new environment.
You *might* want to declare "fatal error!" and exit.
Or it might make sense for `try` (or `try2`) to return
boolean failure which caller is responsible for always
checking and dealing with.

tl;dr: First write down the contract -- what is this
function responsible for? Then adhere to it.

---

Please write down the contract for `slen()`,
maybe by referencing a page like https://manpages.org/strlen .
And write down the motivation for replacing a standard library function.

This could have used the existing helper:
`return indof(s, '\0', maxlen)`.

```
static size_t slen(const char *s, size_t maxlen) {
    char *pos = memchr(s, '\0', maxlen);
    return pos ? (size_t)(pos - s) : maxlen;
}
```

I am unwilling to believe that is correct.
Or alternatively, that its single caller is correct.

In the case of NUL not being found within `maxlen`,
you might possibly want to signal fatal error, and exit.
That would make this an "easy to consume" public API,
one that is easily used correctly and hard to misuse /
misinterpret.

Alternatively, caller must carefully handle both cases.

---

```
            if (tmp > UINT_MAX) my_errno = ERANGE;
```

Are large negative numbers also a concern in `parse_num`?

Are XUL & UL identical on purpose?
There's no comment describing what X means.
I find it unclear, and sort of expected to see UI instead.

This doesn't appear to be correct:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, old_locale);
    if (errno) return false;
    if (my_errno) { 
        errno = my_errno;
        return false;
    }
```

Within `setlocale` we do a ton of work,
including locking, malloc, free.
The value of `errno` may change.
Also, when returning NULL it sets
`errno` to EINVAL.

I recommend you declare `my_errno` (or just `error`) as a boolean,
and adopt a pattern of `error |= some_result`.

Your parse_float & parse_long comments were valuable at one time,
but now is the time to delete them.

---

In `hexstr_top` I see:

```
    ...
    Pixel p;
    ...
    return p;
```

Yikes! Did we just return a stack allocated local?!?

---

Ok, `cache_grep()` is a hundred lines,
more than fits on a single screen without scrolling.
Sorry, I lack the fortitude to wade in there.
Recommend you consider Extract Helper.

---

Overall?

This code is coming along, and clearly some careful thought
has gone into parts of it.
It does not yet have any automated unit tests.

I would not want to accept or delegate a maintenance task
for the code in its current form.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will look into those. I especially appreciate pointing out my `return p;` flub. The `try` function is a new invention and I previously used things like `assert(!fclose(...))` but decided I would want error messages in case of future failures. I will probably just change this to be the equivalent of my `assert_error` macro which aborts on failure, but negate the exit_code. As for the `case XUL:` in `parse_num`, it uses 16 for the `base` argument to `strtoul`, so it's for parsing hex numbers, whereas `case UL` is for decimal.

Comment: Ooohhh! It's hex. I honestly had no idea. _Usually_ my review remarks are along the lines of "fewer comments please!", as I'd rather just read the clear code. But here, there seems legitimate motivation for concise identifiers like XUL, so I guess that increases the documentation burden. You _could_ write a /* comment */ explaining it, but prolly better to point at URL of a man page or similar specification that you adhere to. And as far as assert goes, I'll just say I am fond of two things: (1) **fatal** errors (don't have to reason about what rest of code does), and (2) **diagnostic** err.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with returning a local. Returning a _pointer to local_ would be sad indeed, but `return p;` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

## General Observations

This code is not portable, nor does it even attempt to be portable. The type `ssize_t` is not part of the C programming standard. The standard equivalent is `ptrdiff_t`. The function `getopt()` is not portable. The best code sticks to the C standard as much as possible so that the code can be used on multiple platforms. There is no good reason to have to write the same code multiple times on different operating systems if you don't have to.

The vertical spacing between functions is inconsistent; sometimes there is a blank line and sometimes there is no blank line. Your vertical spacing is your choice, but be consistent. Personally I recommend using one blank lines between functions.

Code that contains commented out code is not ready for code review.

## Don't Hide Possible Changes of Execution

The `DIE(rc, fmt, ...)` macro contains a call to `exit(status)`. While the macro is appropriately named, hiding calls to `exit()` can lead to major problems with maintainability. If for some reason the `DIE` macro was moved into a header file it would not be obvious to someone that needs to maintain the code that `exit()` is being called. One wouldn't want to put `goto` or label definitions into a macro for the same reason.

Is there any reason to use an [exit status](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) other than either `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`? Most of the references to the `DIE` macro use 2, which is a non-standard exit status, there is one reference to `DIE` that does use 1 as the exit status, which could be changed to `EXIT_FAILURE`.

## Complexity

At least 2 functions in the code (`main()` and `cache_grep()`) are 100 or more lines of code. This means they are too complex (do too much). The function `get_resized_pixel_info()` is borderline at 65 lines. A common best practice in programming is to restrict function size to one screen in an IDE or editor. One of the main reasons for this is that a function that is larger than one screen is very hard to understand, which makes writing, reading and debugging much more difficult. A second measure for complexity is the level of indentation - 5 levels of indentation is a lot.

The function `main()` is too complex (does too much). As programs grow in size the use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program.

In the function `cache_grep()` there is a comment `/* init cache */` The code here should probably be a function that is named `init_cache()`. Another possible function in `cache_grep()` is the last `for` loop.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

## Magic Numbers

There are many Magic Numbers in the code (6 and 7 in `cache_fetch()`, 49 in `cache_grep()`, 10 and 16 in `parse_num()`, etc.). It might be better to create symbolic constants for them to make the code more readable and easier to maintain. These numbers may be used in many places and being able to change them by editing only one line makes maintenance easier.

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), because there is no obvious meaning for them. There is a discussion of this on Stack Overflow: [*What is a magic number, and why is it bad?*](//stackoverflow.com/q/47882).

Comment: Thank you for the review. May I ask what you would recommend in place of `getopt`? Just loop through `argv` manually? Also, is `ssize_t` the only nonstandard type I use?

Comment: @Wilson As far as I can tell `ssize_t` is the only non-standard type, I didn't try compiling on Linux so I can't be sure, I was compile on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2022 so not all the include files were available. When I fixed `ssize_t` half of the errors disappeared. I suggest you write your own version of `getopt` and create a library with a header. You can probably find examples online.

Comment: Is it OK to just replace all occurrences of `ssize_t` with `long`? I initially started using `ssize_t` in reaction to some compiler warnings (comparing integer types of different signedness, mainly) and decided in some places to just use the same type that I was seeing MagickCore commands returning. That is likewise why I'm not using standard fixed-size types as I normally do, being concerned about using `uint64_t` expecting it to be the same size as the `long` that some MagickCore function returns, and having trouble later on when compiling on another system.

Comment: @Wilson `unit64_t` is unsigned, `long` is signed., a positive number in `uint64_t` might be a negative number in `long`. If the values are primarily unsigned then [size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) (not `ssize_t`) would be good. If the values are signed `long` might be a good choice.